# Construct a DataTime index from multiple columns of a datadrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am parsing a dataframe from a sas7bdat file and I want to convert the index into datetime to resample the data.

I have one column with the Date which is type String and another column of the time which is of type datetime.time. Does anybody know how to convert this to one column of datetime?

I already tried the pd.datetime like this but it requires individual columns for year, month and day:

```
df['TimeIn']=str(df['TimeIn'])
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df[['Date', 'TimeIn']], dayfirst=True)
```

This gives me a value error:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

[DataFrame column headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI051.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert both the date and time column to str then you can concatenate them and then call `to_datetime`:

```
In[155]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['08/05/2018'], 'TimeIn':['10:32:12']})
df

Out[155]: 
         Date    TimeIn
0  08/05/2018  10:32:12

In[156]:    
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['TimeIn'])
df

Out[156]: 
         Date    TimeIn            new_date
0  08/05/2018  10:32:12 2018-08-05 10:32:12
```